# How to perform logistic lasso in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

The scikit-learn package provides the functions `Lasso()` and `LassoCV()` but no option to fit a logistic function instead of a linear one...How to perform logistic lasso in python?

Comment: I still have no answer to it. I ended up performing this analysis in R using the package glmnet.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Lasso optimizes a least-square problem with a L1 penalty.
By definition you can't optimize a logistic function with the Lasso.

If you want to optimize a logistic function with a L1 penalty, you can use the `LogisticRegression` estimator with the L1 penalty:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
log = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear')
log.fit(X, y)
```

Note that only the LIBLINEAR and SAGA (added in v0.19) solvers handle the L1 penalty.

Comment: lasso isn't only used with least square problems. any likelihood penalty (L1 or L2) can be used with any likelihood-formulated model, which includes any generalized linear model modeled with an exponential family likelihood function, which includes logistic regression.

Comment: Agreed. Originally defined for least squares, Lasso regularization is easily extended to a wide variety of statistical models. In scikit-learn though, the `Lasso` class only includes least-square. Other classes include L1 regularization (`LogisticRegression`, `NMF`, ...), but it is called "L1 regularization", and not "Lasso".

Comment: ah ok. i thought you were referring to lasso generally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `glmnet` in Python. Glmnet uses warm starts and active-set convergence so it is extremely efficient. Those techniques make `glmnet` faster than other lasso implementations. You can download it from [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet_python/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/glmnet_python/)

Answer (score 1):

## 1 scikit-learn: `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`

`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` from scikit-learn is probably the best:

as @TomDLT [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41682039/781938), `Lasso` is for the least squares (regression) case, not logistic (classification).

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = LogisticRegression(
    penalty='l1',
    solver='saga',  # or 'liblinear'
    C=regularization_strength)

model.fit(x, y)
```

## 2 python-glmnet: `glmnet.LogitNet`

You can also use [Civis Analytics' python-glmnet library](https://github.com/civisanalytics/python-glmnet). This implements the scikit-learn `BaseEstimator` API:

```
# source: https://github.com/civisanalytics/python-glmnet#regularized-logistic-regression

from glmnet import LogitNet

m = LogitNet(
    alpha=1,  # 0 <= alpha <= 1, 0 for ridge, 1 for lasso
)
m = m.fit(x, y)
```

I'm not sure how to adjust the penalty with `LogitNet`, but I'll let you figure that out.

## 3 other

#### PyMC

you can also take a fully bayesian approach. rather than use L1-penalized optimization to find a point estimate for your coefficients, you can approximate the distribution of your coefficients given your data. this gives you the same answer as L1-penalized maximum likelihood estimation if you use a Laplace prior for your coefficients. the Laplace prior induces sparsity.

the PyMC folks have [a tutorial here](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/lasso_block_update.html) on setting something like that up. good luck.