# How to plot a ROC curve for a Lasso Regression model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, roc

Lasso, although it's a regression algorithm, can be used as a classifier. Therefore, there should be a way to make a ROC curve and find it's AUC.

###### This is my code for making the model, scaling and standardizing  it:

```
X = data.drop(['Response'], axis = 1)
Y = data.Response

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler() 
scaled_X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
scaled_X_test = scaler.transform(X_test) 

pipline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('model', Lasso(normalize=True))
])

lasso_model = GridSearchCV(pipline,
                           {'model__alpha': np.arange(0, 3, 0.05)},
                           cv = 10 ,
                           scoring = 'roc_auc',
                           verbose = 3,
                           n_jobs = -1,
                           error_score = 'raise')

lasso_model.fit(scaled_X_train, Y_train)
```

##### Now trying to make the ROC curves, one for the training set and one for the test set:

```
# Make a line for the random classification, AUC = 0.5: 
r_probs = [0 for _ in range(len(Y_test))]
r_auc = roc_auc_score(Y_test,r_probs)
r_fpr, r_tpr , _ = roc_curve(Y_test, r_probs)

y_pred_proba = lasso_model.predict_proba(scaled_X_train)[::,1]
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(Y_train,  y_pred_proba)
auc = roc_auc_score(Y_train, y_pred_proba)

#create ROC curve

plt.plot(r_fpr, r_tpr, linestyle = '--', label = 'Random Prediction (AUROC = %0.3f)' %r_auc)
plt.plot(fpr,tpr,label="AUC="+str(auc))
plt.title('Train set ROC')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.show()
```

I get the error that `predict_proba` does not exist for lasso regression, since it is not a classification algorithm. So how can I plot a ROC curve?

Comment: What score do you want to use to make a ROC curve?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Using the `fpr`, `tpr` and `auc`. calculated based on the `Y_train` and `y_pred_proba`.

Comment: the y_pred_proba is the stuff I asked you about, how do you want to produce this from a regression model?

Comment: I think that's what I don't understand.. this code is for a classification model like random forest classifier, I tried to apply it on a regressor and it does not work. What should I alter in the code?

Comment: This is why it does not make sense, regressors do not output class scores, ROC curve is a binary classification method, to use it for regression, you need to have a clear formulation, else it would not be a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lasso is basically linear model with L1 regularization. You can enable this kind of regularization for `LogisticRegression()` using `penalty='l1'` for the same effect (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639557/how-to-perform-logistic-lasso-in-python), for example).

Alternatively, you can try to duct tape a sigmoid function to your `Lasso()` output, but that'd be doing the same thing as above with much more effort.